# Saving inline edited data of ckeditor to mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, ckeditor

I've got CKEditor 4 installed on my local machine and i'm using WAMP Server. But, as I read, there is no option to save content into MYSQL database. I want to create site, when I want to save new data to database, edit data which is already there in my site, fetch data from MYSQL database after editing that data save into MYSQL database.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)! There you can store data into MySQL on your local machine